# Regex Match Only None or One

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use the following if statement with regex but having some trouble:

```
if ! [[ $myText =~ ^[A-Z0-9]{5},[[:space:]]?[\ A-Za-z0-9]+$ ]]; then
        echo "ERROR"
        continue
fi
```

The objective is to allow `YHG6D,test` and `YHG6D, test` but not `YHG6D,  test` (2 spaces and beyond).

I thought using the ? after [[:space:]] or " " would do the trick by limiting the space to either none or one as I want to do, but it doesn't work because I presume having 2 spaces also meets that match criterion. If so, how do I limit the match literally such that if there is no space or one space after the comma it runs the code but if there's more than one space after the comma it throws an error?

And also, I was advised to add the `"\"` in front of the `[A-Za-z0-9]` expression but have no idea what it does and if it is necessary.

Comment: You could specify the range of number of occurrences with braces: `{0,1}` matches between 0 and 1 occurrences of the preceding group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the `\`  in `[\ A-Za-z0-9]+` which matches a space. If you remove it, the regex matches zero or one space between the comma and the word:

```
^[A-Z0-9]{5},[[:space:]]?[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

as tested in https://regex101.com, this matches `YHG6D,test` and `YHG6D, test`, but it doesn't match `YHG6D,  test` or `YHG6D,   test`.

Also, you don't need the `continue` in your `if` statement:

```
if ! [[ $myText =~ [A-Z0-9]{5},[[:space:]]?[A-Za-z0-9]+$ ]]; then
    echo "ERROR";
fi
```

Here is are some tests:

```
$ bash
$ myText="YHG6D,test"; if ! [[ $myText =~ [A-Z0-9]{5},[[:space:]]?[A-Za-z0-9]+$ ]]; then echo "ERROR"; fi
$ myText="YHG6D, test"; if ! [[ $myText =~ [A-Z0-9]{5},[[:space:]]?[A-Za-z0-9]+$ ]]; then echo "ERROR"; fi
$ myText="YHG6D,  test"; if ! [[ $myText =~ [A-Z0-9]{5},[[:space:]]?[A-Za-z0-9]+$ ]]; then echo "ERROR"; fi
ERROR
$
```

The `$`  at the beginning of each line is the bash prompt, so copy the command from the `myTest=...` and paste it into a bash terminal to test.

Comment: Actually that doesn't work either because it shows the error in EVERY instance, no space, one space, multiple spaces.

Comment: If anyone has a solution please comment. Thanks.

Comment: @macuseronline, I'm assuming that you're using bash. I tested using bash on linux, and it works. I'll edit my answer with the tests so that you can see it. Let me know if I made the wrong assumption.

Comment: @macuseronline, if after looking at how I tested, you can't reproduce it. Tell me/us how you're testing so that I/we can help.